# A custom headerView like iPhone contacts image and small UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to get an application that has `UITableview` with a custom header view. I want the header view to be quite similar to the iPhone contacts app (see picture) when you are editing/adding a new contact i.e. a small image to the left and 2 to 3 static text entry cells on the right that look like the `UITableView` Grouped cells.

Whats the easiest way to achieve this design in IB or Code (without Story board)? At the moment it seems like I have to create a Parent `UIView`, add an image on the left and add a `UITableView` on the right and populate it with `UITableViewCell` dynamically. But this seems cumbersome and means I have to implement another class with a `UITableView` delegate protocol to populate the `UITableview` cells in the header.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: You can set a header view (UIView) on a tableview's `tableHeaderView` and then for each section there is a delegate method that returns a UIView for that section. You should check out the TableView programming guide http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451

Comment: mkral - already know that I have to use a "headerView" for my tableview as noted in my question. Question is how do I make my headerView itself contain a set of static UITableView cells (and specifically make it look like iPhone contacts, i.e image on left, and 2 or 3 smaller tablview cell on right).

Comment: Create a UIView that has an UIImageView and a textLabel, this would be the headerView of the table. Then if you want buttons in between the cells utilize the section header or footer delegate methods to create a UIView then add whatever subviews you want to that.

Comment: That's if you're talking about when you're viewing a single contact

Comment: No, i am talking about when you are "EDITING" a single contact. The image view on the left. 3 UITableViewCell on the right. Thats the exact look and behaviour i want to simulate